# unordered_map does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, std

I've tried various implementations in Visual C++ 16.0 (the one that ships with Visual Studio 2010) and I'm getting all kinds of bugs with `std::unordered_map`

For example

```
CKey key = pszName;
auto it = m_Records.find(key);
if (it != m_Records.end())
{
  // we replace existing item (so delete old)
  delete it->second;
  it->second = pRecord;
}
else
{
  const size_t sz = m_Records.size();
  m_Records.insert(std::make_pair(key, pRecord));
  const size_t sz2 = m_Records.size();
  assert((sz + 1) == sz2); // this assertion fails! wtf!
}
```

`m_Records` is a std::unordered_map instance. So I switched to `boost::unordered_map` 1.48. Now this does work but I have another problem elsewhere. Same code above though but the same key keeps getting inserted twice or more. How is it that my map cannot manage the simplest of things and only keep one entry per key?

I have tripled check that hash function and comparison function. I do not believe they are to blame here.

What am I doing wrong?

The type of `m_Records` is either `boost::unordered_map<CKey, CRecord*>` or `std::unordered_map<CKey, CRecord*>`.

`CKey` is defined as such:

```
struct CKey
{
  const wchar_t* m_Str;
  int m_Len;

  CKey(const wchar_t* s)
    : m_Str(s)
    , m_Len(s ? (int)wcslen(s) : 0)
  {
  }

  size_t hash() const
  {
    if (this->m_Len > 0)
    {
      char temp[16];
      memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
      MurmurHash3_x64_128(this->m_Str, (int)sizeof(wchar_t) * this->m_Len, 0, temp);
      size_t hash = *(size_t*)temp;
      return hash;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  bool operator==(const CKey& other) const
  {
    if ((this->m_Len > 0) & (this->m_Len == other.m_Len))
    {
      return (wcscmp(this->m_Str, other.m_Str) == 0);
    }
    // otherwise, they are only equal if they are both empty
    return (this->m_Len == 0) & (other.m_Len == 0);
  }
};

namespace boost
{
template <>
struct hash<CKey>
{
  size_t operator()(const CKey& k) const
  {
    return k.hash();
  }
};
}

namespace std
{
template <>
struct equal_to<CKey>
{
  bool operator()(const CKey& x, const CKey& y) const
  {
    return (x == y);
  }
};
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say when the assertion fails, is key interesting at all?  Could keys be mutated while in the map?  (ie, do they contain pointers to resources others have pointers to?)  Can you produce a MCVE?  What version of `boost`?

Comment: It's all single threaded, no concurrency so I cannot see how anything would change while the insertion or any map operation takes place.

Comment: No, the entire time the key is in the map, not just while you are calling map methods.  Mutating keys in a map (ordered or unordered) accidentally is a common 'oops' that leads to UB and unexpected wierdness.  Keys must be immutable wrt hash and comparison while stored.  Without more details, just a stab in dark.

Comment: No wait. That's it... it's the same memory area! I knew it had to be something like that, let me verify!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was a simple shared memory problem. I was unknowingly not considering that the memory that I used to insert the item came from a temporary variable. While everything was heap memory that remained in place the actual key value (not the hash or bucket position) changed from entry to entry. This in turn led to the above inconsistent and illogical operations.

Lessoned learned, when the nature of the problem is illogical the reason for the problem is likely to be similar in nature. I simply changed the `const char* m_Str` member declaration in `CKey` to `std::wstring m_Str` and that did it.

The fix made the `CKey` struct considerably smaller, which was nice. Substituting my original implementation for this worked just fine.

```
struct CKey
{
  std::wstring m_Str;

  CKey(const wchar_t* s)
    : m_Str(s)
  {
  }

  size_t hash() const
  {
    if (!this->m_Str.empty())
    {
      char temp[16];
      memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
      MurmurHash3_x64_128(this->m_Str.c_str(), (int)sizeof(wchar_t) * (int)this->m_Str.size(), 0, temp);
      size_t hash = *(size_t*)temp;
      return hash;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  bool operator==(const CKey& other) const
  {
    return this->m_Str.compare(other.m_Str) == 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you included what the fixed code snippet looked like.